# xcode source tree and bitbucket

Tags: ios, xcode, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

In order not to make changes to source code from master branch in XCode 5 I've creaded a new branch where I want to add or remove code from existing project. I do see the new branch in Source Tree , above the master branch ,but in bitbucket I don t see the branch. Why is this? Can someone tell me?

Thank you

I would like to specify that I am new to xcode, source tree and bitbucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created branch locally it you probably didn't push it to your origin.

In SourceTree make sure when you are pushing changes to server make sure all branches are marked as "Tracked".

Comment: how do I push changes to server? Can i please help? Where do I see if the branch is marked as Tracked?

Comment: do I just have to click push from source tree?

Comment: Yes click PUSH - this will send your local changes to your remote server. There you can mark all branches or select single one. Make sure you mark all of them to be send - that's all

Comment: and if in xcode I am under the new branch (source control menu) it means that every change will be under the new branch, right?

Comment: Right - after you switch to a branch all changes are directly visible in Xcode and you are working on that branch.

Comment: When I click push on source tree I see both branched (master and the new branch created). i don t want to push anything to master! I did made some changes to my code and I don t want those changes to be visible in master. In this case i only need to select my new branch , right?

Comment: Yep if that's what you need - just mark your branch to be pushed :)

Comment: Thank you!! I want to ask you one more thing. What s the difference between push and commit? In XCODE in source control in working copies i am under my new branch. I want to updated the code. should I do a commit or a push?

Comment: Also if i want to save the project with source code i have in a new workspace how should i do this? I did do File-> Save as WorkSpace but all I was was a .xcode project with no source tree

Comment: Basically commit put all your changes to local repository and push "pushes" them to remote servers. If you want to update code you should use "pull".

Comment: Can you tell me how can I save the source code from xcode into another place?

Comment: Best will be to use: git archive master | tar -x -C /save/path

Comment: I see. Thank you. Some of my files are marked as red in xcode. when i try to open them I can't. The project is still build correctly but I don t know how to change this. Could you give me some tips?:)

Answer (score 1):

You created that branch locally, if you want it to be in the server, you need to push it.

You can do it with this command:

```
git push -u origin myBranch
```